# How to open a new page inside component on button click in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

dashboard.component.ts file

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Http, Headers, Response,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Login }    from './login';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.html',
  template : '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class DashboardComponent {

}
```

module.ts file in which I have defined routes

```ts
 import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }        from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent }          from './app.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  LoginFormComponent,
  DashboardComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am new to angular2, and I am designing a login page. Now I want to open a new page when user is properly authenticated after clicking on submit button . Please suggest me some alternatives of how should I do this? Below is the login.component.ts file . Thanks
Updated code

```ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';
    import {Http, Headers, Response,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { Login }    from './login';
    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'login-form',
      templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
    })

    export class LoginFormComponent {
         constructor (private http: Http,private _router:Router) {}
        data = {
            'email': '',
               'password': ''
        };
        formSubmit (body: Object): Observable<Login[]>{
           let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
            let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
            let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
           var params = "username=" + this.data.email + "&password=" + this.data.password;
           var resp = this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/login", params, options) // ...using post request
                             .subscribe((res:Response) => {
                                 if(res.json().status_code == 200)
                                 {
                                                          this._router.navigate(["../dashboard"]);
                                     console.log("success");
                                 }
                                 } );
                             return;                                          
    }
    }
```

Comment: remove router-outlet from dashboard and append it inside login.component.html and try again , then you will it working but still its not proper way

Comment: Hey, I have removed it from dashboard. Now you know what, when I refresh my login page, the dashboard.html file loads without clicking on the login page only. I want dashboard.html to be loaded after clicking, its now loading dashboard.html file on refreshing the page only

Comment: yes, now it loaded , this is how router works , you need to add that in app.component.html. Now you need to learn about router.

Comment: Will you please upvote my answer and accept it?

Comment: Yeah Sure Bro, Thank you so much . You deserve it .

Comment: Last query Vivek, Now I dont want that router-outlet on login page. I want to open new page dashboard.html after clicking so where should I place this router-oulet now ?

Comment: create app.component.html and place it there , and in routes define 

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
  { path: 'dashbaord', component: DashboardComponent }
];

Comment: Hey sorry bro, done that, still its not opening new page dashboard.html?

Comment: Man , please read about router first and then try to do it.

Comment: Ok Thanks will do that

Answer (score 2):

use

```
constructor (private http: Http,private _router:Router) {}

if(res.json().status_code == 200)
{
 this._router.navigate(["../Dashboard"]);
}
```

This will redirect user to Dashboard , defined in routes.

If you want to learn more about : [Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Inside module :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashbaord', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  .......
})
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for your answer. But can you please tell me the meaning of this line "This will redirect user to Dashboard , defined in routes." I have added the above code as per your suggestion but how to define it in routes.

Comment: for that you need tp read : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-config

Comment: Yes, I have read this. And I have also added it in routes in module.ts file of mine . still it it giving me error. "No provider for router"

Comment: Yes vivek, I have done exactly the same. But now its still giving me error."Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DashboardComponent'"

Comment: For that you need to define <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component.html

Comment: Man you realy need to read this : https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router

Comment: Thanks vivek for your help, but I think I am very close to it. Would you please tell if its app.component.html or app.component.ts file you are talking about ? Thanks. Where do I nedd to add <router-outlet></router-outlet> this ?

Comment: For now add this inside login,component.html , you will get idea how it works

Comment: Thanks Vivek, Now I have added that router outlet in app.component.ts. Now I am not getting any errors, but still it not opening new window ? I know I am asking you too much, but please help? Thanks

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but on clicking submit button I am not able to load the dashboard.html file. I have added that router-outlet in app.component.ts file ? still not working?